# get all keys combination in nested python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I am new to python.. trying to get all the key combinations..Lets say i have dictionary d.

```
d = {'edge': {'edge1': {'interface': {'interface1': {'ip': 10, 'name': 'uplink-to-x'}}, 'name': 'x'}, 'edge2': {'interface': {'interface1': {'ip': 20, 'name': 'uplink-to-y'}}, 'name': 'y'}}}
```

Need output to be:

```
edge["edge1"]["name"]
edge["edge1"]["interface"]["interface1"]["name"]
edge["edge1"]["interface"]["interface1"]["ip"]
edge["edge2"]["name"]
edge["edge2"]["interface"]["interface1"]["name"]
edge["edge2"]["interface"]["interface1"]["ip"]
```

Please help..

Comment: Please show your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the leaf elements like this:

**Python3 Code**

```
d = {'edge': {'edge1': {'interface': {'interface1': {'ip': 10, 'name': 'uplink-to-x'}}, 'name': 'x'}, 'edge2': {'interface': {'interface1': {'ip': 20, 'name': 'uplink-to-y'}}, 'name': 'y'}}}
def nested_print(d):
    for key in d:
        if isinstance(d[key],dict):
            nested_print(d[key])
        else:
            print(key,d[key])
nested_print(d)
```

**Output**

```
ip 20
name uplink-to-y
name y
ip 10
name uplink-to-x
name x
```

**N.B.:** I did not find any element as `edge["edge1"]["name"]` in your given dictionary

`isinstance` builtin function's documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Answer (score 0):

As I can't found ready function to convert nested dictionatry keys into list of tuples a wrote this. With little effort it could be converted into plain text:

```
def to_tuples(dict_, result_list=None, in_line_list=None):
    """convert from nested dictionaty to list of tuples"""
    is_return_list = True if result_list is None else False
    if is_return_list:
        result_list = []
    is_create_new = True if in_line_list is None else False
    for k, v in dict_.items():
        if is_create_new:
            in_line_list = []
        out_line_list = copy.deepcopy(in_line_list)
        out_line_list.append(k)
        if not isinstance(v, dict) or len(v) == 0:
            result_list.append(tuple(out_line_list))
        else:
            to_tuples(dict_[k], result_list, out_line_list)
    if is_return_list:
        return result_list


d = {
    "edge": {
        "edge1": {"interface": {"interface1": {"ip": 10, "name": "uplink-to-x"}}, "name": "x"},
        "edge2": {"interface": {"interface1": {"ip": 20, "name": "uplink-to-y"}}, "name": "y                                            "},
    }
}


for x in to_tuples(d):
    a = [f"""["{key}"]""" for key in x]
    print("edge" + "".join(a))
```

will print:

```
edge["edge"]["edge1"]["interface"]["interface1"]["ip"]
edge["edge"]["edge1"]["interface"]["interface1"]["name"]
edge["edge"]["edge1"]["name"]
edge["edge"]["edge2"]["interface"]["interface1"]["ip"]
edge["edge"]["edge2"]["interface"]["interface1"]["name"]
edge["edge"]["edge2"]["name"]
```